# Прозрачная кнопка в HTML onclick?

Tags: html

Помогите сделать именно в данном коде **эту кнопку непрозрачной**
Не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script>
  var colorArray = [ "#f2f3f4" ]; // массив с цветами
  var i = 0; // итератор

  function changeColor() {
    var currentColor = colorArray[i];
    document.body.style.background = currentColor;
    localStorage.setItem('backgroundColor', currentColor);
    i++;
    if( i > colorArray.length - 1){
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  
  function setDefaultColor() {    
    document.body.style.removeProperty( 'background' );
    localStorage.removeItem('backgroundColor');
  }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="changeColor()" value="Изменить фон">
<input type="button" onclick="setDefaultColor()" value="По умолчанию">

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem('backgroundColor');
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое значение как `transparent` (прозрачный), он является цветом и применяется в таких свойствах как `background-color`, `color` и т.п.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>Прозрачный фон кнопки</button>
```

Comment: Добрый день, я не знаю почему, но не работет у меня!

Comment: Что- я делаю не так!???????

Comment: А можете именно к коду который сверху прописать что бы у меня работало именно в HTML

Comment: Пожалуйста..........

Comment: `Что- я делаю не так!?` - не читаете документацию.. Для вашего кода пойдёт следующее `input {background-color: transparent}`

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример:
[Клик](https://codepen.io/bookamba/pen/jOMvOmg?editors=1111)

html:

```
<button id='hidden-btn' class="hidden-btn"></button>
```

css:

```
body {
  background: #cc77ee;
}
.hidden-btn {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:none;
  background: transparent;  
  outline:none;
}
```

jQuery код:

```
$("#hidden-btn").on("click", function() {
  console.log("hidden-btn click...");
});
```